# Elasticsearch pagination with Scroll not working with aggregations

Tags: database, elasticsearch, query-string, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

Hello I have around 3000000 records for the new_ip aggregation.I cannot retrieve more than 50000 records in one query so I started using scroll API but the scroll_id I get isn't giving me the aggregations data but giving rest of the data which i am not interested in
Here is my query

```
  curl --location --request GET 'http://myserver:9200/myIndex/_search?scroll=5m' -u elastic:abcjkks --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "org": "BPL"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2023-04-11T10:30:00",
              "lte": "2023-04-11T17:30:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "ips": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "new_ip",
        "size": 10000
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

This is the response I get for the new_ip aggregations in buckets

```
"buckets": [
    {
      "key": "170.39.44.9",
      "doc_count": 73
    },
```

[image]
Post that when i try to use this scroll_id and fetch the next set of results I dont see the aggregations anymore giving my new_ips

Here is the next request with scroll_id

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://myserver:9200/_search/scroll' -u elastic:abcjkks --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{
  "scroll": "5m",
  "scroll_id": "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"
}'
```

I get response like this **without the aggregations tag as in previous response**
Can someone please help
[image]